# Php's password_hash encoding for HTTP basic authentication

Tags: passwords, php, javascript

**My problem:**

I need, basic authentication over HTTP (client can't afford HTTPS). So I don't worry if communication is not encrypted. I just want to prevent some user from sniffing and using the password (site only used to upload photos and those photos are public.).

Toolbox of what I have at my disposal:

1. Javascript
2. PHP
3. Sha512.js

The SHA algorithm is the same in both PHP and JS:

**The proof:(?)**

```
<?php 
$password= "password";
echo hash('sha512',$password);
//outputs: b109f3bbbc244eb82441917ed06d618b9008dd09b3befd1b5e07394c706a8bb980b1d7785e5976ec049b46df5f1326af5a2ea6d103fd07c95385ffab0cacbc86
?>
```

While in JS (all my files are encoded in utf8)

```
document.getElementById("hiddenField").value
= JS.sha512("password");
//outputs b109f3bbbc244eb82441917ed06d618b9008dd09b3befd1b5e07394c706a8bb980b1d7785e5976ec049b46df5f1326af5a2ea6d103fd07c95385ffab0cacbc86
```

However I cannot simply send the same hash on every connection, else anyone can sniff it and send it to connect.

So my idea was to use `password_hash()` function as salt generator.

The salt is public, the hash of (password+salt) is public, but password is private and never sent as clear text: the server will compute (hopefully) the same hash as the one in JS from the client and verify that both hashes match.

The problem is that regardless of what I do, I'm unable to get the same output when I **hash the output of that function(password_hash)**. It seems to be something related to encoding.

I want to use `password_hash()` because it already keeps into account a lot of security stuff:

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("hiddenField").value
= JS.sha512("password" +  document.getElementById("publicToken").value);
```

I put the "password_hash" content into another hidden form field that I call "publicToken". Regardless of what I do I'm unable to get the hash match:

```
<?php 
$salt = ut8_encode(password_hash("another_password")); //doesn't work either
```

In the end, what do I have to do to get a correctly encoded salt?

```
<?php
$salt = //... one time usage salt.. but what to put here?
```

Comment: Hi Dario, you seem to have conflicting requirements: `So I don't warry If communication is not crypted. I just want to prevent some user can sniff and use the password`. Also any crypto you do in JS is worthless, if the JS itself is not at a minimum served over HTTPS. Finally, "can't afford HTTPS" seems incredibly weird, since there are plenty of very cheap cert providers, maybe even free... This sounds like an invented problem to solve the solution.

Comment: Have you considered using the already existing HTTP Digest Access Authentication?

Comment: You're assuming that an attacker won't simply man in the middle the login page and strip any client side encryption you use or inject a JavaScript keylogger.

Comment: Any example of free web service that allow to store few Hundred megabytes of webiste + Database and HTTPS? If you give the example then the problem is invented else not

Answer (score 1):

I realize your client cannot afford a standard HTTPS certificate, but honestly, even a free SSL certificate is likely to be far better than what ever you can concoct here.

In this situation, all you are doing is making the browser-side hash the user's password, and all one has to do to get in is send a matching hash. If you decide to do this, you definitely need to hash the password again on the server side, but it is still no replacement for SSL.

More on it here: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Answer (score 1):

Without public key cryptography and a way to verify the identity of the server (in other words, HTTPS), the unfortunate truth is that there is simply no way to secure the communication to an acceptable level. I would not even advise trying, for fear of getting a false sense of security. No matter how much you hash and salt, it will only be minimally better than sending the plaintext password and trivial to break.

If your client cannot afford a certificate, I would recommend taking a look at [StartSSL](https://www.startssl.com/). Their basic level certificates are completely free; I believe they're valid for 1 year with unlimited renewal.

Another project worth looking at is [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). They've trying to make the process of getting a certificate much simpler and more accessible, so they've developed a way to completely automate the process of issuing (free) certificates. The service is not live yet, unfortunately; they plan to start issuing certificates this summer. Quoting their page:

> Anyone who has gone through the trouble of setting up a secure website
> knows what a hassle getting a certificate can be. Let’s Encrypt
> automates away all this pain and lets site operators turn on HTTPS
> with a single click or shell command.
>
> When Let’s Encrypt launches in mid-2015, enabling HTTPS for your site
> will be as easy as installing a small piece of certificate management
> software on the server:
>
> `$ sudo apt-get install lets-encrypt`
>
> `$ lets-encrypt example.com`
>
> That’s all there is to it! https://example.com is immediately live.
>
> The Let’s Encrypt management software will:
>
> - Automatically prove to the Let’s Encrypt CA that you control the website
> - Obtain a browser-trusted certificate and set it up on your web server
> - Keep track of when your certificate is going to expire, and automatically renew it
> - Help you revoke the certificate if that ever becomes necessary.
>
> No validation emails, no complicated configuration editing, no expired
> certificates breaking your website. And of course, because Let’s
> Encrypt provides certificates for free, no need to arrange payment.

Comment: It's not matter of certificate. The client can't afford any hosting at all so it is using altervista wich does not provide HTTPS regardless of the fact I can generate free certificates. Then I'll revert to plan B wich is sending email to client with confirm link before any anction on the site (i'll use HTTPS of its webmail service)